# Given the hexadecimal code of a character, how to convert it to the corresponding character in CL program?

Tags: character-encoding, ibm-midrange, hex, journal

Now I need to find a particular entry in a journal using a CL program. The way I use to locate it is to DSPJRNE to put the journal entries in an output file, then use OPNQRYF to filter the desired one. The file is uniquely keyed so my plan is to compare the journal entry data with the key. The problem is that one of the key is a packed decimal so in the journal entry it is treated as hexadecimal code of characters and displayed as some strange symbols. So in order to  compare the strings I need to convert the packed decimal key into the corresponding characters. How to achieve this in CL? If using CL is not possible, what about RPG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, the CVTCH MI instruction will convert hex to char but I would not go that route; neither in CL nor RPG.  Rather, I would take James' advice with a few additional steps.

```
DSPJRNE OUTFILE(QTEMP/DSPJRNE)
QRY input file DSPJRNE, output file QRYJRNE, select only JOESD
CRTDUPOBJ PRODUCTION_FILE QTEMP/JRNF DATA(*NO)
CPYF QRYJRNE JRNF FMTOPT(*NOCHK)
```

This will give you an externally described file with the exact same layout as your production file.  You can query that, etc.

Comment: Dieter Bender has a tool that will do that for you: http://www.bender-dv.de/index.html

Comment: Why is CVTCH MI not recommended? Is direct copy of journal entry to the production file really going to align the data correctly according to the fields?

Comment: What will you do with the record once you've found it?  Print a report of records updated? What if you don't find it by key, and you need to look at other columns?  Having it in an external file is more flexible than brute force searching by column and CVTCH in my opinion.  As for the CPYF, yes, it will exactly align the fields.  Don't CPYF to your production file!!!!! CPYF to a duplicate copy.

Comment: Try James' solution.  It is very much like Dieter's ANZJRN.

Comment: Because I know the key of the record in the file so I should not miss it. The original value of that record is needed but due to the logic in the current program it is not preserved and overwritten by subsequent updates so I have to find it from journal entry. Anyway I tried your way today and it worked. That's all I need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling journal entries for a specific file you can dump them into an externally described file with a clever use of SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE QTEMP/QADSPJRN LIKE QSYS/QADSPJRN

ALTER TABLE QTEMP/QADSPJRN DROP COLUMN JOESD

CREATE TABLE QTEMP/DSPJRNE AS (SELECT * FROM QTEMP/QADSPJRN, FILE-LIB/FILE) 
WITH NO DATA

DSPJRNE ... OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OUTFILFMT(*TYPE1) OUTFILE(QTEMP/DSPJRNE) 
ENDDTALEN(*CALC)
```

Comment: Well, I have already known how to dump all the entries to a file. The problem is how to find that particular entry I am searching for.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question.  Once you get the journal into an externally described file it's just a matter of querying based upon the field / value you are looking for.  By overlaying the record buffer on the external descriptions all of the conversion is handled for you.

Comment: James, I think he's looking to parse packed fields inside JOESD.

Comment: You got my point Buck. Sorry that my question might be a little confusing. The journal entry stuff is merely the background story.

Comment: @BuckCalabro My steps overlay the JOESD field over the external descriptions for the original file therefore unpacking binary/packed/etc.

Comment: I see that now.  Missed the implicit join.  Very nice.